# XML to XML using XSLT transformation -- skip one loop header contents and show loop headers

Tags: xml, xslt

Trying to get xml output from below input to xml output
xml  --> xml output using xslt
Need help

1. After transformation need to have  this header `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
2. skip  <G_1>
   <ORDER_NUM>135115</ORDER_NUM>
   </G_1>
3. Rest should show as is include loop headers

Can any one help to get xslt for same

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!---------input xml ------------------------------------------>
<DATA_DS>
    <G_1>
        <ORDER_NUM>135115</ORDER_NUM>
        <ACK_HEADER>
            <SENDER>9211111</SENDER>
            <RECEIVER>92511111</RECEIVER>
            <TRANSACTION_SET>CANCELED</TRANSACTION_SET>
            <ORDER_NUM>111115</ORDER_NUM>
            <ACK_LINE>
                <GL_COMPANY_ID>16881</GL_COMPANY_ID>
                <GL_DIVISION_ID>54880</GL_DIVISION_ID>
                <ITEM_DIVISION_ID>A</ITEM_DIVISION_ID>
            </ACK_LINE>
            <ACK_LINE>
                <GL_COMPANY_ID>161</GL_COMPANY_ID>
                <GL_DIVISION_ID>500</GL_DIVISION_ID>
                <ITEM_DIVISION_ID>G</ITEM_DIVISION_ID>
            </ACK_LINE>
        </ACK_HEADER>
    </G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--Desired output -->
<DATA_DS>
        <ACK_HEADER>
            <SENDER>9256510000</SENDER>
            <RECEIVER>9253070000</RECEIVER>
            <TRANSACTION_SET>CANCELED</TRANSACTION_SET>
            <ORDER_NUM>35115</ORDER_NUM>
            <ACK_LINE>
                <GL_COMPANY_ID>1601</GL_COMPANY_ID>
                <GL_DIVISION_ID>5400</GL_DIVISION_ID>
                <ITEM_DIVISION_ID>AG</ITEM_DIVISION_ID>
            </ACK_LINE>
            <ACK_LINE>
                <GL_COMPANY_ID>1601</GL_COMPANY_ID>
                <GL_DIVISION_ID>5400</GL_DIVISION_ID>
                <ITEM_DIVISION_ID>AG</ITEM_DIVISION_ID>
            </ACK_LINE>
        </ACK_HEADER>
</DATA_DS>
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--Tried with this xslt -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA_DS">

    <xsl:for-each select="G_1">
            <xsl:for-each select="ACK_HEADER">
                
                <xsl:element name="Sender">
                    <xsl:value-of select="SENDER"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="RECEIVER">
                    <xsl:value-of select="RECEIVER"/>
                </xsl:element>
        
<xsl:for-each select="ACK_LINE">
                    <SoHeader>Line start here</SoHeader>
                    <xsl:element name="GL_COMPANY_ID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="GL_COMPANY_ID"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="GL_DIVISION_ID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="GL_DIVISION_ID"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- ACK_LINE -->
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- ACK_HEADER -->
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- DATA_DS -->
    
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<!--got this output -->
<SENDER>9256510000</SENDER>
   <RECEIVER>9253070000</RECEIVER>
   <TRANSACTION_SET>CANCELED</TRANSACTION_SET>
   <PO_NUMBER>40X293825</PO_NUMBER>
   <PO_DATE>20220119</PO_DATE>
   <SO_NUMBER>35115</SO_NUMBER>
   <GL_COMPANY_ID>1601</GL_COMPANY_ID>
   <GL_DIVISION_ID>5400</GL_DIVISION_ID>
   <ITEM_DIVISION_ID>AG</ITEM_DIVISION_ID>
   <HEADER_ALLOWANCE_TYPE/>
```

missing

1. After transformation need to have  this header `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
2. skip  `<G_1> <ORDER_NUM>135115</ORDER_NUM> </G_1>`
3. Rest should show as is include loop headers

Can any one help to get xslt for same

Comment: `ACK_HEADER/ORDER_NUM` is already in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one template matching the `DATA_DS` element, which creates an element with the same name (using `<xsl:copy>`) and for its content copies the `ACK_HEADER` element with all its descendants (using `<xsl:copy-of>`):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="DATA_DS">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="G_1/ACK_HEADER" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Heiko TheiBen Thank you, it worked. really appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

Or:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G_1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ACK_HEADER"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```